# Android runs Alarm Manager daily, every day

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I have a problem with Android alarm. It runs only once at the scheduled time and does not run again in the following days.

What I wanted to know is if it is necessary to reconfigure the alarm, once the onReceive method is executed.

this code goes in Principal (MainActivity) onCreate() method:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //other initializations

            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,22);
            today.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutos);
            today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            Utils.setAlarm(alarmID, today.getTimeInMillis(), Principal.this);
    
  }
```

This are Principal's methods:

```
  public static class Utils {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        public static void setAlarm(int i, Long timestamp, Context ctx) {

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, i, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            alarmIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://" + System.currentTimeMillis())));
            alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timestamp, pendingIntent);
            
        }
    }

    public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("check", " ALARM RECEIVED!!!");

            ClientTCP2 myATaskYW = new ClientTCP2();
            myATaskYW.execute(context);

        }
    }
```

Should I reconfigure the alarm, in the AlarmReceiver's onReceive method?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I reconfigure the alarm, in the AlarmReceiver's onReceive method?

Yes. `setAndAllowWhileIdle` triggers the alarm exactly once. You would need to call `setAndAllowWhileIdle` again to set the next alarm.

Comment: Thanks. 
Do you know why the alarm shoot when you start the application for the first time? That is, the first time I open the application it shows me the push notification and then at the set time. And I just want him to show me the notification at the set time

Comment: Well, your `today` value will be in the past if it is `23:00` for instance, causing your alarm to immediately fire. Sounds like you should be adding a day if it is already past your specific time of the day

Answer (score 1):

Julián Oviedo
here is my Sample code from my Application it can be useful for you.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = AlarmManager.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (vibrator != null) {
            vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        }

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Android")
                .setContentText("Android MIT class")
                .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "NotificationDemo",
                    IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            if (notificationManager != null) {

                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
            }
        } else {
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
            }
        }


    }


}
```

and i called my alaram using activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int min, hour;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Button btn_pickAlarm, btn_setAlarm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_pickAlarm = findViewById(R.id.pick_alarm);
        btn_setAlarm = findViewById(R.id.set_Alarm);

        //for huawei background service enable
        if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) /*!sp.getBoolean("protected",false)*/ {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("headline").setMessage("text")
                    .setPositiveButton("protected", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //sp.edit().putBoolean("protected",true).commit();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
        }

        btn_pickAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                min = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                        hour = selectedHour;
                        min = selectedMinute;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm set at: " + hour + ":" + min, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, hour, min, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();


            }
        });

        btn_setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                long _alarm;

                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent broadcast;

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);


                broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                        12341234,
                        notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                wakeupcall.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
                    _alarm = wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + 1);
                else
                    _alarm = wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis();


                if (alarmManager != null) {


                    if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, broadcast);
                    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, broadcast);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I hope this sample will helpful for you best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for such an important answer. But I see that once the onReceive method is executed, the alarm is not reset. Does this code run the alarm every day? 
or does it only fire it once in the set time?

Comment: yes it will due to these lines if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
                    _alarm = wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + 1);
                else
                    _alarm = wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis(); but keep in mind to use services also for long running criteria.